# Why is my bitcoin core not downloading any blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I am using Centos 7 and I installed the newest version of bitcoin core.
I just want to run a full node to download all the blocks.
According to their [documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#other-linux-daemon), the first time we start bitcoin core, it will start automatically to download the blocks.

This is my /.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf file:

```
datadir=/.../blocks
server=1
txindex=1
rpcport=8332
rpcuser=<something>
rpcpassword=<something>
```

After I run `bitcoind -daemon`, `bitcoin-cli getblockcount` gives me `0`.

Is there anything wrong with the ports?

I tried `netstat -na | grep 8333`, and it gives me this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8333            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      1 <***>:40706     <***>:8333     SYN_SENT
tcp6       0      0 :::8333                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

And `netstat -na | grep 8332` gives me:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8332          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8332                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Output of `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`:

```
{
  "chain": "main",
  "blocks": 0,
  "headers": 0,
  "bestblockhash": "000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "mediantime": 1231006505,
  "verificationprogress": 1.835803992430469e-09,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010001",
  "size_on_disk": 293,
  "pruned": false,
  "softforks": {
    "bip34": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 227931
    },
    "bip66": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 363725
    },
    "bip65": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 388381
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 419328
    },
    "segwit": {
      "type": "buried",
      "active": false,
      "height": 481824
    }
  },
  "warnings": ""
}
```

Result of `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`:

```
{
  "version": 200000,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.20.0/",
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "localservices": "0000000000000409",
  "localservicesnames": [
    "NETWORK",
    "WITNESS",
    "NETWORK_LIMITED"
  ],
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 0,
  "networks": [
    {
      "name": "ipv4",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "ipv6",
      "limited": false,
      "reachable": true,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    },
    {
      "name": "onion",
      "limited": true,
      "reachable": false,
      "proxy": "",
      "proxy_randomize_credentials": false
    }
  ],
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "incrementalfee": 0.00001000,
  "localaddresses": [
    {
      "address": "<***>",
      "port": 8333,
      "score": 1
    }
  ],
  "warnings": ""
}
```

I know the question is kind of dumb but please help me figure out what's wrong.

Edit:

`bitcoind` always freezes at this:

```
Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sipa.be
2020-07-07T04:16:00Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.btc.petertodd.org
2020-07-07T04:16:00Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.sprovoost.nl
2020-07-07T04:16:11Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bluematt.me
2020-07-07T04:16:12Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.emzy.de
2020-07-07T04:16:12Z Loading addresses from DNS seed dnsseed.bitcoin.dashjr.org
2020-07-07T04:16:23Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoinstats.com
2020-07-07T04:16:23Z Loading addresses from DNS seed seed.bitcoin.jonasschnelli.ch
2020-07-07T04:16:23Z 202 addresses found from DNS seeds
2020-07-07T04:16:23Z dnsseed thread exit
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What is the output for `bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo`?

Comment: @RaghavSood I just edited it in the question.

Comment: can you run bitcoind without the daemon option? do you see any error?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo oh yea there's an error: `Error: Cannot obtain a lock on data directory /home/zmengaa/.bitcoin. Bitcoin Core is probably already running.` I think I also used another machine to run `bitcoind` a few days ago. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: I can delete the whole ./bincoin folder and run bitcoind again, is it gonna help? @vincenzopalazzo

Comment: Maybe yes, but is the bitcoin core is already running, the bitcoin core should be print another error. I think that you run bitcoin with two different used (like sudo and you normal used). Before to cancel this directory you can run chmod 777 `/home/zmengaa/.bitcoin`

Comment: I edited it in the post, should it be right? Do I just wait for it to continue or is there anything wrong? Thanks! @vincenzopalazzo

Comment: Mh I posted the wrong command, I'm sorry, I think that you should use the recursive command, try to run this  run `sudo chmod - R 777`

Comment: What is the result of `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`? From the other info you have posted, it looks like you don't have any connections. Make sure there isn't anything preventing you from making outbound connections to port 8333.

Comment: I edited it. @AndrewChow But I'm not sure what the output means. Onion is not reachable, so do i need to do any setting about "tor" or something? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you specifically want to be using tor connections, there's no need to setup tor stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have 0 connections. Your node isn't connecting to other nodes on the network. It is able to connect to the DNS seeders and get node IPs to connect to, but something is preventing it from making the actual connection itself.

Make sure there isn't something preventing your node from making outbound connections to port 8333. This could be a firewall, an antivirus software, or even your Internet service provider.